# Checking whether a column has proper decimal number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe (**input_dataframe**), which looks like as below:

```
id        test_column
1           0.25
2           1.1
3           12
4           test
5           1.3334
6           .11
```

I want to add a column **result**, which put values **1** if **test_column** has a **decimal value** and **0** if **test_column** has any other value. data type of **test_column** is string. Below is the expected output:

```
id        test_column      result
1           0.25              1
2           1.1               1
3           12                0
4           test              0
5           1.3334            1
6           .11               1
```

Can we achieve it using pySpark code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse decimal token with `decimal.Decimal()`

Here we are binding the code inside a UDF then using `df.withColumn`

```
import decimal
from pyspark.sql.types import IntType

def is_valid_decimal(s):
    try:
        # return (0 if decimal.Decimal(val) == int(decimal.Decimal(val)) else 1)            
        return (0 if decimal.Decimal(val)._isinteger() else 1)
    except decimal.InvalidOperation:
        return 0

# register the UDF for usage
sqlContext.udf.register("is_valid_decimal", is_valid_decimal, IntType())

# Using the UDF
df.withColumn("result", is_valid_decimal("test_column"))
```

Comment: this solution is not working for value decimal.Decimal("12"), it should return 0 in such cases.

Comment: Ohh. I did not check that!! I updated the answer now. @rajatsaxena

Comment: Its perfectly matching the above mentioned scenario, just wanted to check if we can have solution for value 12.0, in this case it should be considered as decimal, but current solution does not recognize it as decimal.

Comment: @mrsrinivas this looks like not working for me, i am getting `AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute '_isinteger' ` Which version of pyspark are you using and which python version, i am using latest spark2.2 and python3.6.3 version.

Comment: python version is 2.7.2