# Pyspark Schema update/alter Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I need to read a csv file from S3 ,it has string,double data but i will read as string which will provide a dynamic frame of only string. I want to do below for each row

1. concatenate few columns and create new columns
2. Add new columns
3. Convert value in 3rd column from string to date
4. Convert values of column 4,5,6 individually from string to decimal

```
Storename,code,created_date,performancedata,accumulateddata,maxmontlydata
GHJ 0,GHJ0000001,2020-03-31,0015.5126-,0024.0446-,0017.1811-
MULT,C000000001,2020-03-31,0015.6743-,0024.4533-,0018.0719-
```

Below is the code that I have written so far

```
def ConvertToDec(myString):
    pattern = re.compile("[0-9]{0,4}[\\.]?[0-9]{0,4}[-]?")
    myString=myString.strip()
    doubleVal="";
    if  myString and  not pattern.match(myString):
       doubleVal=-9999.9999;
    else:
     doubleVal=-Decimal(myString);
    return doubleVal

def rowwise_function(row): 
    row_dict = row.asDict()
    data='d';
    if not row_dict['code']:
        data=row_dict['code']
    else:  
        data='CD'
    if not row_dict['performancedata']:
        data= data +row_dict['performancedata']
    else:  
        data=data + 'HJ'
    // new columns
    row_dict['LC_CODE']=data
    row_dict['CD_CD']=123
    row_dict['GBL']=123.345
    if rec["created_date"]:
        rec["created_date"]= convStr =datetime.datetime.strptime(rec["created_date"], '%Y-%m-%d')
    if rec["performancedata"]
        rec["performancedata"] = ConvertToDec(rec["performancedata"])

    newrow = Row(**row_dict)
    return newrow

store_df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("C:\\STOREDATA.TXT", sep="|")
ratings_rdd = store_df.rdd
ratings_rdd_new = ratings_rdd.map(lambda row: rowwise_function(row))
updatedDF=spark.createDataFrame(ratings_rdd_new)
```

Basically, I am creating almost new DataFrame. My questions are below -

1. is this right approach ?
2. Since i am my changing schema mostly is there any other approach

Comment: Seems an odd bounty question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Spark dataframes/sql, why use rdd? You don't need to perform any low level data operations, all are column level so dataframes are easier/efficient to use.

To create new columns - `.withColumn(<col_name>, <expression/value>)` ([refer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn))
All the if's can be made `.filter` ([refer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter))

The whole `ConvertToDec` can be written better using strip and ast module or `float`.

Comment: How do i alter existing columns ? like ConverttoDec how do i do it ? if i should not use row_wise function

Comment: You can pick a column using: `df['col_name']` and make necessary changes. I would suggest use withColumns so that you have both old and new columns and in the end just add a select to pick required columns.

Comment: If you are more comfortable with sql then you may create a view and use that.. [Additional reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for the answere it was helpful , you mean to say i can alter both existing and new column with  "withColumn" ? can you give example for decimal parsing with precession for withColumn

Comment: If  i to  have manipulate 10 columns , is  processing  each row one time  like the one i did in my code is better as i deal with all columns once or is it using withColumn

Comment: Row iteration the way you have done, would be inefficient. Its the long form of doing the dataframe column operation.
Use `withColumn` to add new columns by performing operations then just choose required columns in the end using a `.select`...


Sample code: [decimal check example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46598993/2142994), check that and maybe replace function as required.. 
[string to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4643991/2142994)